# Need to halt a Confirm window of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have been struck up in a condition where i need to halt the Confirm box. This is what I have done:

```
function onBeforeClientInsert(record) {
    var eventtype = parseInt(record. < %= CEO.FieldEvaluator.GetEvaluatorByDId("EVENT_TYPE_ID").GetFieldDataFieldId() % > );
    var begindate = record. < %= CEO.FieldEvaluator.GetEvaluatorByDId("BeginDate").GetFieldDataFieldId() % > ;
    var enddate = record. < %= CEO.FieldEvaluator.GetEvaluatorByDId("EndDate").GetFieldDataFieldId() % > ;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Data.aspx/CheckInsertRecord",
        data: "{EventType:'" + eventtype + "',BeginDate:'" + begindate + "'," + "EndDate:'" + enddate + "' }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {

            if (msg.d == "No duplicate") {

            } else {
                alert(msg.d);
                eval("var data = " + msg.d + ";");

            }
            var i = 0;
            alert(i);
            alert(data[i]);
            do {
                $("#beginDate").html(data[i].BeginDate);
                $("#eventTypeID").html(data[i].EVENT_TYPE_ID);
                $("#endDate").html(data[i].EndDate);
                $("#beginlatlong").html(data[i].BeginLATLONG);
                $("#endlatlong").html(data[i].EndLATLONG);

                var modal = document.getElementById('Div1');
                modal.style.display = '';
                modal.style.position = 'fixed';
                modal.style.zIndex = '100';
                modal.style.left = '30%';
                modal.style.top = '10%';


                var screen = document.getElementById('modalScreen');
                screen.style.display = '';
                i++;
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to continue?") == false) {
                    hide();
                    continue;
                }


            }

            while (msg.d != null);
        }
    });


    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to insert this new record ?") == false) {
        hide();
        return false;
    }
    if (Page_ClientValidate("<%= CEO.GridUtils.Global_ValidationGroupName%>")) {
        hide();
        SetPostBackCause('INSERT');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So,the problem has been that

```
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to insert this new record ?") == false) {
    hide();
    return false;
}
```

would be run immediately after the confirm box

```
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to continue?")==false){
    hide();
    continue;
}
```

But i want it to be halted until the user clicks something on the first confirm box. Can u please let me know how to do this? Also Can u let me know any other way to do this, if I'm approaching it in wrong way?

Comment: Once you get this code to work, **please** post it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for cleanup suggestions.

Comment: @Matt: sure I'll post it

Answer (score 2):

## Ajax is asynchronous.

You need to move **all** dependent code into the `success` callback.

```
success: function (msg) {
    // snip ...
    
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to insert this new record ?") == false) {
        hide();
    }
    if (Page_ClientValidate("<%= CEO.GridUtils.Global_ValidationGroupName%>")) {
        hide();
        SetPostBackCause('INSERT');
    }
}
```

You *could* use [`async: false`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) to make the request sychronous but I **do not** recommend this.

Comment: I tried this... but the second confirm box is not getting called

Answer (score 1):

You need to place all of this:

```
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to insert this new record ?") == false) {
        hide();
        return false;
    }
    if (Page_ClientValidate("<%= CEO.GridUtils.Global_ValidationGroupName%>")) {
        hide();
        SetPostBackCause('INSERT');
        return true;
    }
```

within your AJAX callback if you want it to run after the first dialog.  Currently, you set the callback, and then call the code above.  If your internet connection was really slow, the first dialog you are seeing could theoretically come after the second you are seeing.

Comment: I tried it to keep it in success function but the second conform box does'nt show up..

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the async: false option to $.ajax?